# Calculate Z Values from a plane normal

Tags: math, linear-algebra, eigen, plane

we need to fit a set of points (x,y,z) to plane and get fitted value of Z - Zi at a point (Xi,Yi).

We have used Eigen Library for plane fitting. https://gist.github.com/ialhashim/0a2554076a6cf32831ca

Now we have the normal to the plane and centroid of all points.

How can I can calculate the value of Z axis at a point (xi, yi) with the following information?

1. Centroid of all points
2. Normal to the fitted plane

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the distance `d` to the plane of a point `r=(xi,yi,zi)`.

You have the plane normal `n=(nx,ny,nz)` that should be a unit vector, and a single point on the plane `p=(px,py,pz)`.

```
d = nx*(xi-px) + ny*(yi-py) + nz*(zi-pz)
```

which is the dot product between the normal `n` and the relative position `r-p`.

Or, if you want the equation of the surface of the plane, then solve the equation below for `zi`

```
nx*(xi-px) + ny*(yi-py) + nz*(zi-pz) = 0

zi = pz - (nx*(xi-px)+ny*(yi-py))/nz
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I take centroid as the single point on the plane? When I used Centroid as the point, I get correct values for Z.

Comment: Yes, take the centroid for `p`.